# T_INLINE_HTML? What's wrong with this?

Tags: php, html, switch-statement

```
<? switch($data['type']) : ?>
<? case 'log': ?>

    <? while ($row = $data['loop']->fetch()) : ?>
        <table class="t-errors">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>IP:</b> <? echo $row['LogShellIP']; ?>
                    <b>Command:</b> <? echo $row['LogShellCommand']; ?>
                    <b>Executed:</b> <? echo $row['LogShellReturn']; ?>
                    <b>Time:</b> <? echo format::time($row['LogShellTime']); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <? endwhile; ?>

<? break; ?>

<? case 'fatal': ?>
<? case 'warning': ?>
<? case 'notice': ?>
<? case 'unknown': ?>

    <? while ($row = $data['loop']->fetch()) : ?>
        <table class="t-errors">
            <tr>
                <td <? if ($row['LogErrorSeen'] == 0) { echo 'class="e-selected"'; } ?>>
                    <b>String:</b> <? echo $row['LogErrorString']; ?>
                    <b>File:</b> <? echo $row['LogErrorFile']; ?>
                    <b>Line:</b> <? echo $row['LogErrorLine']; ?>
                    <b>Context:</b> <? echo $row['LogErrorContext']; ?>
                    <b>Ip:</b> <? echo $row['LogErrorIP']; ?>
                    <b>Time:</b> <? echo format::time($row['LogErrorTime']); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <? endwhile; ?>

<? break; ?>
<? endswitch; ?>
```

I'm getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_INLINE_HTML, expecting T_ENDSWITCH
>   or T_CASE or T_DEFAULT in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Smooth
>   Framework/tpl/terminal.tpl.php on line
>   33

Where line `33` is the line `2` of this script. This is inserted in a template context. What's wrong with this? He is expecting a `T_CASE` and that's what is there!

Comment: THe error might be lurking in any of the 31 lines you've ommited

Comment: First off, don't use short-tags.  And don't keep breaking in and out of PHP context like that, it's **really** ugly.  If you fix that, you'll probably find the error goes away right away.

Comment: @Mchl, not at all. PHP error lines are referring always to the previous or current line. So that Error in line 33 could be in line 33 or 32, not previous. Since the 32 is shown, why didn't PHP stopped at 32 instead?

Comment: @Charlie: In this case, you're right.  But in the general case the error can be anywhere in the file.  The line number quoted is only where the *compiler/parser* realized the error, not where it actually occurred.  It could be 30 lines back.  In this case is not.  Reformat your code and you'll be fine...

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli: Do not be so sure about that ;) Depending on what you have in previous lines, a missing comma or a `?>` in a `//` comment can possibly manifest many lines below.

Comment: @Charlie: No, if a parse error occurs in line 32 it can be, that the actual fault is already in line 11.

Comment: @ircmaxell, @Mchl, @nikic Yeah, thanks. I did got it with ircmaxell's comments. ;) There were no needs of 3 comments. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

merge line 1 and 2

```
  <? switch($data['type']):
     case 'log': ?>
```

see the comment in this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) (jeremia at gmx dot at 28-Jan-2008 02:52)

Comment: Exactly: [LXR: language_parser.y](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#405). No `T_INLINE_HTML` allowed there.

Answer (score 3):

The parser expects a T_CASE token but finds the newline after `switch($data['type']) : ?>`.

```
switch (1) : ?> <? case 1: break; endswitch;
```

gives a parse error and so does

```
switch (1) : ?>\n<? case 1: break; endswitch;
```

while

```
switch (1) : ?><? case 1: break; endswitch;
```

does not. ;-)